# Local Storage: How does it behave on mobile devices? Is it safe to use? What are the pitfalls? Need advice from devs who have used it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, local-storage

I have an Angular11 + Firebase app and I need to implement a caching feature on a form section of the app. Its a dynamic from, which can contain many fields depending on use case.

My goal here is to save the user input on LocalStorage so that if something wrong happens (network issues, reloading the page etc...) this stored data will be used to rehydrate the UI.

Up to this moment, if there's a page reload, all input data is lost what is pretty frustrating for users so...My question is: Can I trust the LocalStorage API for this job across Anroid/iOS devices?

I know the Local Storage API works mostly fine on desktop browsers but I hear there are pitfalls when it comes to using it on mobile devices. The thing is that my users rarely access the app on a desktop, so I need a solution that will work on mobile devices and surprisingly I couldn't find any conclusive information about it online so...

Can anyone out there share some knowledge/links/tips/personal experiences about this issue?

I have little time to come up with a solution so any info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell if `localStorage` is a good fit for your use case based on the details you provided, but in general you can use it to store data between sessions. If you need to cache data only for a single session (until the page is closed) you can use `sessionStorage`.

Regarding compatibility, also depends on the specific versions and browsers of mobile devices you need to support. As long as your target browsers have support there shouldn't be any major differences with desktop.

You can check for compatibility in [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=localstorage) and use the pattern described [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern) to check if `localStorage` is available:

```js
var storage;
var fail;
var uid;
try {
    uid = new Date;
    (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
    fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
    storage.removeItem(uid);
    fail && (storage = false);
} catch (exception) {}

if (storage) {
    // Use `storage` e.g.
    storage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to provide further detail on my requirements. Any additional knowledge would be much appreciated